# Как динамически выделить память в Linux?

Tags: linux, ассемблер, память, malloc

Пишу на ассемблере. Необходимо реализовать функцию динамического выделения памяти, чтобы расширять оную и брать, сколько нужно. Linux. Вероятно, системные вызовы нужны будут. Brk, mmap и т.д. Грубо говоря, malloc: чтобы память, занимаемая процессом, расширилась и можно было получить указатель на непрерывные n байт. Архитектура — aarch64, но ссылка на решение или нужный syscall приветствуются.

Comment: Чем функции из libc (mmap, malloc и т.п.) не устраивают? Если вы работаете под linux (т.е. не bare metal), то никаких проблем с их вызовом из асма я не вижу

Comment: Хочется разобраться самому. Пишу компилятор — негоже сишные наработки брать. Уровень ещё ниже. Тем более те самые библиотечные функции как-то реализовали, а значит, это возможно :)

Comment: Компилятор на ассемблере? Зачем? Возможно вы не поняли еще, но любая компиляция это всего лишь **преобразование одного текста в другой**.  Что тут может дать ассемблер?

Comment: Другое дело, если вы хотите разобраться, как это все реализовали? Тогда лучше начать снизу, сделать начальный загрузчик и что-то вроде простой ОС со своими форматами загрузочных модулей, схемой загрузки кода в память (тут важное решение -- вы будете использовать виртуальную память или нет?) и т.д. / Опять же, компилятор к этому никак не относится.

Comment: Можно реализовать компилятор на языке высокого уровня, конечно. Но в конечном итоге он будет генерировать код на ассемблере. И тогда мне нужно приноровиться писать на ассемблере, чтобы понять, как программы будут работать. Для этого и заручился целью написать компилятор на чистом ассемблере.

Comment: Если хотите разобраться с выделением памяти  -- напишите свой аналог malloc/realloc, который выдает запрошенную память из предоставленного блока памяти. Можете попробовать (обдумать идею и реализовать ее) сделать это для блока shared memory (подсказываю, проблема в том, что разные процессы будут видеть этот блок по разным виртуальным адресам). (Но и тут ассемблер совсем не нужен)

Comment: @avp, нет-нет, создание ОС меня пока ни коим образом не заботит и не прельщает :D. Я считаю Linux удобной и продуманной, но не нахожу информации о том, как выделить память динамически. Ужель в исходники закапываться?

Comment: @avp, любезный, так мой вопрос и заключался в том, как реализовать свой malloc/realloc ._.

Comment: Ну, для освоения ассмблера (imho, конечно же) лучше всего читать результаты `gcc -S` (и соответствующую ISA, естественно)

Comment: Gcc, равно как и Clang, используют рантайм-библиотеки, как я понял. Я о ключе -S, конечно, знаю и использую, но там на выходе загоняется число в регистр (аргумент) и вызывается функция malloc. А где потом линковщик её ищет — я без понятия. Поэтому и прошу ссылку на реализацию.

Comment: Пишу на Android, используя Clang.

Comment: Как сделать простой (насколько простой?) malloc? Берете блок памяти. Делаете структуру, в которой размечаете это блок на свободную и занятую области. При запросе памяти -- находите нужный кусок среди свободных областей и помечаете его как занятый. При возврате памяти -- перемещаете ранее занятый кусок в свободные и по возможности объединяете смежные свободные кусочки в одну область побольше. Это основная идея. Детали либо обдумывате сами, либо ищите в сети (что вам интересней...)

Comment: Алгоритм ясен, непонятно только, как запрашивать память у системы. Насколько мне известно, Linux выделяет для программы определённую область оперативки, которую можно расширить посредством системных вызовов. А какие конкретно вызовы нужны — спрашиваю тут.

Comment: Для реальных тестов -- для начала я бы взял статический блок -- `static uint64_t Memory_blk[MEM_SIZE];` Потом можно использовать  mmap

Comment: Вот не хватает знаний. Толстые книги по Linux API — явно не выход. Уверен, что в недрах Интернета разъясняющая статья/ответ отыщутся.

Comment: Может и остались еще добрые люди, а мне лениво что-то коням сферическим писать

Comment: Ладно, продолжу бороздить вакуум ;)